# Execute Poplesoft services/code in parallel using multiple threads

Tags: c#-4.0, peoplesoft, peoplesoft-app-engine

I am consuming peoplesoft services via .net application written in C# language. The issue is when I am calling peoplesoft services parallely using Task Parallel Library functions, the peoplesoft service error out due to concurrency checks set in peoplesoft Component Interface.

Please suggest if there is a way to execute Peoplesoft code which does database operation parallely? Since this could be not be done in .net end, I am open for suggestions to achieve this in peoplesoft end, I have access to application designer.